# input redirection on CMD

Tags: c, windows

Well, I am learning programming in C, and I got an assignment to get 3 characters from an input text file into 3 variables and then print their ASCII values.
I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a,b,c;
  printf("Insert 3 characters:\n");
  a=getch();
  b=getch();
  c=getch();
  printf("%d, %d, %d",(int)a,(int)b,(int)c);
}
```

I opened a text file (input.txt) and wrote there: "**`abc`**".
I managed to compile the code with the MinGW compiler, and on the CMD window that I opened in the folder of the .exe file, I wrote: "`Task.exe <input.txt`".
The program ran normally. I mean, it waited for me to input 3 characters.

What have I done wrong in my work?
help me please :)

Comment: BTW, learning and using Linux is probably worthwhile!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467865/how-to-use-redirection-in-c-for-file-input

Comment: `getch()` --> `getchar()`

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to read from an input *text file*.

Why don't you use [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) to open a file handle, and [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) to read from it?

You could perhaps use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/). Don't forget to use the resulting count.

And of course, you should call [fclose](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/). Using [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/) is useful to handle error cases.

So start your code with something that checks that your program has an argument, then `fopen` it:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
 if (argc<2) { fprintf(stderr, "missing program argument\n");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 FILE* fil = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if (!fil) { perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then run `Task.exe input.txt` in your console (no redirection needed!).

You should take the habit of reading the documentation of every function you are using, of testing failure cases, of compiling with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -g`), and of using the debugger (`gdb`).

Comment: If i would learn it, i would use it, can you write the syntax of the CMD command?

Comment: I did write `Task.exe input.txt`; however, honestly I never used Windows.... What exactly is `CMD` for you? Some command terminal?

Comment: Notice that `getch` is probably Windows specific.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but the code that you mentioned is like chinese to me, I am a begginer, without any extra knowledge in programing.

Comment: `cmd.exe` (AKA the Windows "Command Prompt") is a command-line shell, or 'command interpreter'. In the 80s it was OS/2's replacement for DOS `COMMAND.COM`. Microsoft's business relationship with IBM soured, so NT OS/2 was redesigned as Windows NT (1993), with cmd ported as a Win32 console application. The OP could run from some other shell such as PowerShell or bash. Either way, a new console server (conhost.exe) is spawned if one isn't inherited from the parent process. `_getch` calls Win32 `ReadConsoleInputA` to read input directly from the console instead of using C stdio.