# C - Using angle brackets in command lines

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

At the moment I have this code:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    char * txtfile = argv[1];

    fp = fopen(txtfile, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
    free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;
}
```

It's function is to read a file line by line and print its contents along with the number of the number of characters on that line but however when I try to pass angle brackets such as '>' or '<', it terminates and it doesn't give me any output. I have a task where I'm required to take it as a command line argument namely in the form of:

```
./hello < output.txt
```

to read a file.

Note, the spec I was given says that my code will be tested in that specific manner, I'm just wondering how I could use the "<" without the quotations.
*(added OPs comment for clarity on the unchangeable requirment.)*

Is there any way I can work around this problem? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `>` is a shell command. Ist will redirect the output of the previous command to a file. `<`   will read from a file.

Comment: `./hello < output.txt` doesn't actually pass `<` and `output.txt` as arguments.

Comment: What **is** the problem you are trying to work around? Your code will be tested by feeding it the content of output.txt as input. So all your ways to read in input (e.g. `scanf()`) will receive text from that file. Your program will have the goal to read something from user and react to that input. If that is not true, then please give an example of oen of your programming assignments and explain why using `scanf()` (or somethign else) is not applicable to access the test input.

Comment: Well the parameter that will be fed will be the name of the text file as a command line argument (so I don't see how you can use scanf), and it just so happens that the angle bracket will be there. What I want to know, is the role of the angle bracket and how I can make the code work properly because at the moment it doesn't.

Comment: Does it say anywhere that the file name will be fed as command line parameter? I bet it will be among the first things to be entered by user, i.e. be the first line **inside** the output.txt file.

Comment: Well I might not have been clear in explaining what my spec was but I wish it was that flexible. Unfortunately this is part of the autotests which my code will be submitted to so it's not like I have a choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use redirection in C for file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467865/how-to-use-redirection-in-c-for-file-input)

Comment: Please try a simple input forwarder (read input and just print if) with a file of that name existing and having some "hello input redirection world" input. Does it show the content of the file "output.txt"? Wouldn't that be the workaround for not having the expected command line parameters?

Comment: You must check that you have a non-null `argv[1]` before you try opening it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Isn't it guaranteed that there will be none?

Comment: The code unconditionally tries to open `argv[1]` (via `txtfile`).  This is bad.  You're correct, @Yunnosch, that there won't be a non-null `argv[1]` for the invocation `./hello < output.txt` — there will only be `argv[0]` and `argc == 1` and `argv[1] == NULL`.  So the check I propose will help prevent the program crashing, and will help demonstrate that neither the `<` nor the redirected file name `output.txt` is given as an argument to the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added your check-idea to my answer, assuming that you do not mind.

Comment: NP — comments are fair game, especially with credit given.

Comment: What is problem to read from stdin ? In your case passing file like this "./prog < file" you can read it line by line from that file without using argv

Comment: the name: `read` is a well known C library function.  Suggest using `bytesRead`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a problem to work around.
Your code will be tested by feeding it the content of output.txt as input. That will be exactly as if a user types in the input, to become standard input to all ways of reading input. This is called "input redirection".
So all your ways to read in input (e.g. `scanf()`) will receive text from that file.

Presumeably your program will have the goal to read something from user and react to that input in a specified way. If that is not true, then please give an example of one of your programming assignments and explain why using `scanf()` (or something else) is not applicable to access the test input.

To put it differently, if your problem is that you cannot access the "command line parameters" (which actually are not command line parameters, so you cannot access them as such), then try this:
Make a simple input forwarder (read input and just print if) with a file of that name existing and having some "hello input redirection world" input. Build and run it from commandline as specified.
Does it show the content of the file "output.txt"? I expected so.
Wouldn't that be the workaround for not having the expected command line parameters?

Picking up the recommendation by Jonathan Leffler, check whether there is a non-NULL argv[1] argument. If there is none, then study the concept of input-redirection to find out where the input might be which you need for your program.

Comment: I don't think you understand, the spec is to take in a text file as a command line argument in the form of : ./hello < first.txt. So scanf won't be useful at all. What I'm trying to ask is why the angle bracket is there, and how I am to treat it.

Comment: One of us does not understand the spec of how your code will be tested, I agree. Can you quote the description in your question, please? I am sure we can sort out our misunderstanding.

Comment: Have a look here to verifiy that the syntax you describe in your question is exactly what indicates that there will be no command line arguments to your program: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm

Comment: Also have a look at the duplicate I linked. I did not find it before answering.

Comment: Thanks heaps! And sorry for the lack of clarity too! I kind of ignored scanf but I had no idea about the input redirection as I didn't even learn unix yet. It's solved now.

Comment: @Calahan: Input redirection works in Windows at the CMD.EXE prompt too — and presumably with PowerShell too.

Comment: Well now my question would be how do you loop through the file line by line?

Comment: Yes, that would be another, separate question. Make one and you will either be given help, or, mor likely, pointers to dozens of duplicates. Try searching StackOverflow for an answer first. Searching for "[c] loop through the file line by line" has 248 hits.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

./hello "<" > output.txt

It will pass `<` as commad line arg and output wll be redirected to output.txt.

Comment: That doesn't work either, and the spec I was given says that my code will be tested in that specific manner, I'm just wondering how I could use the "<" without the quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes, like this:

```
./hello '<' output.txt
```

Single quote inhibits all interpretation of a sequence of characters.

Comment: That works perfectly fine, but the tests on my code will not contain the quotations around the bracket and that's my current dilemma.

Comment: Can't you modify the tests to include quotes around the bracket?

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. outputs the results from each call to `getline()`

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( void )
{
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t getlineStatus;


    while ((getlineStatus = getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1) )
    {
        printf("Returned value from getline(): %ld :\n", getlineStatus);
        printf( "number of bytes allocated for line: %lu\n", len );
        printf("%s\n\n", line);
        free( line );
        line = NULL;
        len = 0;
    }

    free( line );
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running ubuntu linux 16.04. using the source file for the input:

```
untitled2 < untitled2.c
```

results in:

```
Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
#include <stdio.h>


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
#include <stdlib.h>


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
int main( void )


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
{


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //FILE * fp;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    char * line = NULL;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    size_t len = 0;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    ssize_t getlineStatus;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //char * txtfile = argv[1];


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //fp = fopen(txtfile, "r");


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //if (fp == NULL)


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    while ((getlineStatus = getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1) )


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    {


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        printf("Returned value from getline(): %ld :\n", getlineStatus);


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        printf( "number of bytes allocated for line: %lu\n", len );


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        printf("%s\n\n", line);


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        free( line );


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        line = NULL;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
        len = 0;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    }


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120



Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //fclose(fp);


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //if (line)


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    //    free( line );


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
    return 0;


Returned value from getline(): 1 :
number of bytes allocated for line: 120
}
```