# how to accept pathname from stdin for open() system call?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I need to accept the pathname when I run my C script on linux from stdin.

I have tried doing:-

```
 int file = open(STDIN_FILENO, O_RDONLY)
```

"file" is always assigned to -1 ( file not opened).

I expect running

```
./myScript < test.txt
```

to pass "test.txt" to open

```
 open("test.txt", O_RDONLY); // expected after running the previous command
```

Comment: `STDIN_FILENO` already is an open descriptor. The shell has called the open for you and moved the resultant filedescriptor onto `STDIN_FILENO`, which is a macro for `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use redirection in C for file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467865/how-to-use-redirection-in-c-for-file-input)

Comment: That's different problem. I need to use the system call open()

Comment: Read from stdin into a char array.  Use the value in the char array as the filename for the open.  See `fgets()`

Comment: fgets() is also not a system call. I cannot use <stdio.h> library

Answer (score 0):

> I expect running
>
> ./myScript < test.txt
>
> to pass "test.txt" to open

That's an incorrect expectation. When you use shell's redirection operator `<`, it opens the file `text.txt` and assigns the file descriptor to your program's standard input i.e., file descriptor 0 (STDIN_FILENO). So there's no need to open the file again - it's been done already.

If you want to expect your program to receive the filename as an argument then don't use `<` and pass it as an argument:

```
./myScript test.txt
```

Now you would be able to receive the filename in `argv[1]` of your program and use  it in the call to `open` system call.

---

NB: C isn't a scripting but a compiled language, so you'd better get the terminology correct (such as "C program" instead of "C script").