# Use a txt file to send input to my C program

Tags: c, bash, input

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int main()   
{   
  int n, count = 1;   
  float x, average, sum = 0;   
  printf("How many numbers do you wish to test: ");  
  scanf ("%d",&n);   
  while (count <= n)   
     {   
      printf ("Enter number #%d: ",count);   
      scanf("%f", &x);   
      sum += x;   
      ++count;   
     }   
    average = sum/n;   
    printf("\nThe Average is: %.2f\n", average);   
}
```

This program asks the user for a certain amount of numbers to be entered and then calculates the average of those numbers. My question is, if I want to use a file called inputfile.txt to input the data, how would I use redirection without typing in the data from STDIN? So instead the data comes from the inputfile.txt. Also how would I set up the inputfile.txt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467865/how-to-use-redirection-in-c-for-file-input

Comment: Create `inputfile.txt` with your favorite text editor, then `./a.out < inputfile.txt`?

Comment: google is your friend ... search for ... c language read stdin    .... its a critical skill learning how to ask questions in google ... this might sound obvious however it is a skill to simplify the issue into something google can pick up

Comment: User234567, Curiously, why did you code using `float` and not `double`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd put your numbers in a text file, one per line.

Then, because you need to enter the count first, use the `wc` command

```sh
$ gcc your_code.c

$ cat numbers
10
20
40

$ { wc -l < numbers; cat numbers; } | ./a.out
How many numbers do you wish to test: Enter number #1: Enter number #2: Enter number #3:
The Average is: 23.33
```

I use the braces to group the output of both wc and cat into a single input stream for your program.

---

A bash-specific technique: read the numbers from the file into a shell array, and then use printf to output the length of the array and the array elements.

```sh
$ readarray -t nums < numbers

$ printf '%d\n' "${#nums[@]}" "${nums[@]}" | ./a.out
How many numbers do you wish to test: Enter number #1: Enter number #2: Enter number #3:
The Average is: 23.33
```

Comment: For the OP's particular program, it doesn't even have to be one per line.  The numbers just need to be separated from each other by whitespace (including, but not limited to newlines).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Even whitespace not needed with OP's code.  `"2-456.0+789"` works.  Judicious white space helps us humans.

Comment: `wc -l` and `readarray` only work if it's one per line. I'm not storing the count in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a file with compatible content. And then redirect using `<`. For example, file content is:

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

The first number is number of numbers. Others are numbers you want to calculate average. Save this file as any name like `file.txt` and then call your program like this: `./a.out < file.txt`.

You should think about `<` is only redirects file content to stdin. So file content should same with writing answers from stdin interactively. If you set first number to 5 in file and then set 4 different number, your program will ask for 5th number(sorry). Your program won't ask for 5th number. See comments.

Comment: I don't think the program will ask the user for the 5th number: stdin will be closed by that point, so I think the program will *reuse* the 4th number.

Comment: @glennjackman OP's code looks OK, even if not idiomatic.